# CSS Set height as % of container

Tags: html, css

I have a HTML coded as;

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="fl left">
   <div class="fl right">
</div>
```

Now if I give width of 25% to the left div, it takes it correctly (e.g. if container=1000px, it would give left a width of 250px)

But if I specify height as 25% to the right div, it does not calculate it correctly (It seems like it ignores the % height)

How do I make the child div % height to be calculated correctly?

Comment: you're missing the closing tags for the child divs, but i suppose it's only in this example. however, it looks fine to me http://jsfiddle.net/Tetaxa/9xpTg/

Comment: can you show us your CSS code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you did with the width, you have to define an height for the `container`.
See  http://fiddle.jshell.net/z9GY8/2/

Note: 
Close your divs e.g. `<div class="fl left"></div>` (edit : Close with `</div>`)

Comment: Close your divs with a `</div>` tag, not a self-closing tag.  Unless you're using XHTML, the slash means nothing -- and you shouldn't be using XHTML anymore, in most cases.  Even there, though, self-closing tags should be used solely for void elements (ones that can not contain elements or text themselves).

Comment: Thx a lot...Actually bcoz I am using a fluid layout (all in %), I'll not be able to use fixed px for the container height...So how do I set it with % only ?

Comment: If you haven't fixed px, add to the CSS `*{height:100%}`. This will take the whole height. Hope this solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the closing tag of child div.
And as far as possible don't put % for any element. Give them particular measurement.

Answer (score 0):

You need to close your div tags like so:
`<div class="container"><div class="fl left"></div><div class="fl right"></div> </div> </div>`

Also as said previously, it may be better in this example to use absolute measurements for your heights and widths,  like (250px), rather than percentages.

Answer (score -2):

HTML doesn't have ability to calculate height by percentage. It impossible to do just with HTML.

You should use javascript (jquery) for this target.

Like this example:
$('div.right').heght($(document).height() / 100 * 25); // So it will be 25 %.

Comment: -1, http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WrjwaqZfjIY. HTML doesn't have the ability to *do* anything, it's just a markup language. On the other hand, JavaScript shouldn't be used to do something as simple as this, HTML + CSS will be fine.

Comment: Suitable Adaptation : `$('div.right').height($('div.container').height() / 100 * 25);`

Comment: Why you unvote an answer. It works. If you have any other suggestions just let us know. Don't be rude.

Comment: @Sergey: I down voted because it's a bad solution. JavaScript should not be used for very simple layout tasks. No offence intended, I can see why I came off as rude, but try not to take it personally.